# Tomcat9 used environments variables on server.xml

Tags: tomcat, service, systemctl

I try to insert environments var on conf/server.xml file

I follow the tomcat documentation : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/EnvironmentPropertySource.html

on conf/server.xml

```
...
redirectPort="${tomcat_redir}"
...
```

on terminal

```
$ env | grep tomcat_redir
8443

echo "org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource" >> conf/catalina.properties
```

after this configuration, I restart tomcat service. I try to curl

```
curl -Ik https://10.0.0.1:8443
curl (7) Failed to connect on 1.0.0.1 port 8443: Connection refused

curl -I http://10.0.0.1:8080
200

cat /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat9
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat


Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_PID=/var/tomcat/%i/run/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/var/tomcat/%i/"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

#RestartSec=10
#Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I expecte to have a response code 200 on 8443

but when I stop/start service with bin/shutdown.sh and bin/startup.sh
it works !

So I don't know when I use systemctl restart tomcat.service, it doesn't works but when I use the script it works.

Even if, I changed

```
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource"
```

on systemctl tomcat.service, I execute daemon-reload, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

when you run script on terminal, /etc/profile is work. But, systemctl must be set environments in tomcat.service, it seem as cannot loading enviroment from /etc/profile. so, just add one line on tomcat.service: Environment="tomcat_redir= 8443"

Comment: thanks for your aswer. I add Environment="tomcat_redir= 8443"
after systemctl daemon-reload
but nothing changed...